# Wordpress posting comment

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress website. And I just received this specific error message

> You are bullshit user

when I post a comment on any page.

I checked `wp-comments-post.php`, but I got nothing. Before, it was working, but now I don't know why this message comes up.

Please advise me what may be the problem. Here is a snapshot of this insulting message:

[image: Here is a snapshot of this insulting message]

Comment: i think it is hacked

Answer (score 0):

1.go to the below path in your wordpress file.

```
  /wp-admin/options.php
```

2.open options.php in notepad then find your error message by ctrl+f

3.If there delete it.

check with the Roles and capabilities for users under below link

[User roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Answer (score 0):

"You are bullshit user" is the message the [Block Spam Comments plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-spam-comments/) displays if it thinks your comment is spam.

From [block-spam-comments.php](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/block-spam-comments/trunk/block-spam-comments.php):

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'verify_block_spam_comment' );

function verify_block_spam_comment( $commentdata ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['is_legal_comment'] ) )
        wp_die( __( 'You are bullshit user' ) );

    return $commentdata;
}
```

That plugin doesn't appear to be written very well and hasn't been updated in a while. You can find much better plugins, like Akismet which actually comes with WordPress itself.

You may be seeing the error because some other script is preventing this script's JavaScript from executing. Or, do you maybe have JavaScript turned off? This plugin uses jQuery, but doesn't tell WordPress to enqueue jQuery, so if your theme isn't enqueuing it and no other plugin is enqueuing it you might just not have jQuery loaded. It's hard to know exactly why it thinks you're a spammer every time.

If you want to keep this plugin but make the message friendlier, the author did use one of WordPress's translation functions, so you can replace the message with code like this in a custom plugin or your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'too_much_bullshit_around_here', 20, 3);
function too_much_bullshit_around_here($translated_text, $text, $domain) {
    if('You are bullshit user' === $text) {
        return "If you are a spammer I must politely ask you to leave.";
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```